# Getting a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with netbeans, weblogic, and fast-swap set to true

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

I am trying to enable fast-swap deploys in my development environment. I am using netbeans 7.4 with weblogic 12.1.2

I believe fast-swap should be supported in this version of weblogic. After I modify my weblogic.xml to have true and deployed it, my project fails with the following stack trace.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.addDays(Ljava/util/Date;I)Ljava/util/Date;
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>       at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.filters.SiteMeshFilter$beaVersion0_74.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:98)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.filters.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.filters.SiteMeshFilter.beaAccessobtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.filters.SiteMeshFilter$beaVersion0_74.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:56)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.filters.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at com.mysite.web.common.filters.GeneralFilter.doFilterInternal(GeneralFilter.java:41)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at weblogic.servlet.utils.FastSwapFilter.doFilter(FastSwapFilter.java:66)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.addDays(Ljava/util/Date;I)Ljava/util/Date;
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.CardService.getPendingCardsCount(CardService.java:205)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.CardService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2baa1223.invoke()
>       at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>       at com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.interceptor.EhCacheInterceptor.invokeCacheable(EhCacheInterceptor.java:142)
>       at com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.interceptor.EhCacheInterceptor.invoke(EhCacheInterceptor.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.CardService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ccf60c81.getPendingCardsCount()
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.myTestService.refreshWebUserSetting(myTestService.java:807)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.myTestService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd0077e3.invoke()
>       at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.model.services.myTestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$18c3abc1.refreshWebUserSetting()
>       at com.mysite.webstore.interceptors.MyRequestInterceptor$beaVersion0_143.header(MyRequestInterceptor.java:216)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.interceptors.MyRequestInterceptor.header(MyRequestInterceptor.java)
>       at com.mysite.cms.interceptors.ContentMyRequestInterceptor.postHandle(ContentMyRequestInterceptor.java:50)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.interceptors.MyRequestInterceptor.beaInvokeSuper(MyRequestInterceptor.java)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.interceptors.MyRequestInterceptor$beaVersion0_143.postHandle(MyRequestInterceptor.java:160)
>       at com.mysite.webstore.interceptors.MyRequestInterceptor.postHandle(MyRequestInterceptor.java)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:911)
>       ... 71 more

On other pages I hit different java.lang.NoSuchMethodErrors. On pages that dont use any library classes it does not error, everything works. I have noticed that it is always on the first call to a class in a library outside of my main project. How come it does not see the classes from these libraries? Do I need to explode them? If so, how? Google was unhelpful when trying to find this information out.

When I turn fast-swap to false, everything works.

How to get fast-swap to work with my libraries? I wont be modifying the libraries. I just want my project to be able to see the library classes! I do not wish to switch to use JRebel or any 3rd part tool to help with redeploys/hot deploys.